# Saving local overwrites and reapplying them as modified after git pull

Tags: git, workflow

We use a configuration management repository for our big project. I have to change some of the general settings for some of my special work cases.

Therefore I have to modify some of the configuration files, but still want to be able to save these changes, when I update the project from remote (`git pull`). Ideally my changes should show as modified in `git status`

I did not find a question about this special work flow case so far. So whats the best approach?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use a branch and commit your changes to it. Then you update this branch from remote via rebase. This is the basic workflow of git. As far as I understand your problem, that is your workflow as well.

Comment: @Nils_M well I explicitly do want my local config changes to show up in git diff and marked as modified, so I can always easily check what changes are currently active. I actually use a branch and cherry-pick+reset --mixed my local changes onto master/working-branch to achieve this. I posted this question for information on better ways to achieve this and posted my current solution. E.g. I'm not sure if using git pull / git pull --rebase is save for unindexed changes. git stash seems to be a good solution too.

Comment: ah ok, I understand. I didn't attribute enough weight to the "show as modified" part. Thanks for clearing that up. Using `git pull --rebase` for unindexed changes is not possible. But you can automate the stash via the `rebase.autostash` flag in your config. Or the `--autostash` option of `rebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) to store your working folder (uncommitted) changes.

After the `git pull`, you can reapply those changes using `git stash pop`.

Comment: i somehow thought, git stash would bite me on changes to the same file, but it actually performs a merge (just tried it). So for just one version this would be the easier approach. Though my approach backups the changes.

Comment: @dfherr Yes, I believe the stashed changes are treated internally as a commit. When you `stash pop` those changes are merged with the current state of the working directory and it's also possible to have merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

wolfs answer is possibly the easiest and most convenient way. When you want to (remotely) backup your changes or keep different versions, here is another approach:

Create a branch and then commit the modified version there.

Then you apply the changes of that commit as modified to your current head via:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
git reset --mixed HEAD~1
```

[reset --mixed](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) option: changed files are preserved but not marked for commit. It's the default option.

When you want to save a different personal modified version, create a new branch and proceed as above.